# AZURE WEB APP: Problem: fatal: Authentication failed for 'webapp url'

Tags: azure-web-app-service

Good day I am new on web developing and want to ask on how to fix this error in the terminal of Azure webapp service, `git push azure main` this is the command I keep inserting inside the terminal but the response is always this `Password for <webapp url>` and I don't know what password I should enter

therefore I browse the internet and still stuck on this, the fixes I tried is removing some credentials on windows credential, changing the HTTPS to SSHS, configuring global password, and lastly installing the GCM from github thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- In `Azure Portal`, first we need to create `Azure App service` with the required run time stack.

[image]

- You will get this option, if we deploy our App using `Local Git`.

[image]

- We need to provide Credentials while pushing the code from local GitHub.

[image]

- You will get the Credentials from `Azure Portal` => `App Service`.
- Navigate to `Azure Portal` => Your `App Service` (which you have created in first step) => `Deployment Center` => `Local Git/ FTPS credentials`.
- We can use the existing `Application scope` Username and Password or can create new `User scope` and use them.

[image]